# error: C2065: 'QTcpSocket' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt creator 5.10 in windows 7.

When I build my project error occurs:
 error: C2065: 'QTcpSocket' : undeclared identifier
error: C2065: 'QTcpclient' : undeclared identifier

```
    QTcpSocket *tcpClient;
    tcpClient = new QTcpSocket(this);
```

Comment: And did you `#include <QTcpSocket>`?

Answer (score 1):

In your .pro file add `QT += network` and make sure to `#include <QTcpSocket>`.

Comment: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QTcpSocket': No such file or directory

Comment: try #include <QtNetowrk/QTcpSocket>